# How to clean up the rootfs partition or increase the size

Tags: disk-usage

Can't figure out how I should clean up my rootfs partition. It's 95% used, with total of 9.1G in space. Isn't that much for a root partition? This is my ouput of `df -h` command:

```
    /# df -h
Filesystem                                              Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs                                                  9.1G  8.2G  471M  95% /
udev                                                     10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs                                                   1.6G  740K  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/disk/by-uuid/55421528-015b-4bfc-8490-74b4cc25a2b4  9.1G  8.2G  471M  95% /
tmpfs                                                   5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                                                   4.9G  536K  4.9G   1% /run/shm
/dev/sdb6                                               203G  647M  192G   1% /home
```

What is taking so much space because I can't find any large files in **/var/cache**. I've tried with `apt-get clean` and `apt-get autoremove`, with no luck on getting more space. How can I find the files that are taking up so much space? How can I do it securely so I don't mess up some important files? Or do I need to increase the size of the partition instead?

Edit:

The output of `du -sh /*`

```
0   /0
7.2M    /bin
26M /boot
0   /dev
12M /etc
4.0K    /example.conf.json
588M    /home
0   /initrd.img
212M    /lib
3.1M    /lib32
4.0K    /lib64
16K /lost+found
24K /media
4.0K    /mnt
1015M   /opt
du: cannot access `/proc/15453/task/15453/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `/proc/15453/task/15453/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `/proc/15453/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `/proc/15453/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
0   /proc
52M /root
1.3M    /run
9.5M    /sbin
4.0K    /selinux
8.0K    /srv
0   /sys
40K /tmp
6.4G    /usr
350M    /var
0   /vmlinuz
```

Output of `du -sh /usr/* | sort -rh`:

```
4.1G    /usr/share
1.9G    /usr/lib
382M    /usr/bin
39M /usr/include
36M /usr/sbin
6.3M    /usr/lib32
1.9M    /usr/lib64
1.4M    /usr/x86_64-linux-gnu
588K    /usr/local
92K /usr/src
36K /usr/var
12K /usr/man
4.0K    /usr/games
```

Comment: Can you show `du -sh /*`

Comment: A big files you can search by `find / -type f -size +100M 2>/dev/null`

Comment: @Costas Yes, I edited the question with the output of du -sh /*

Comment: On my Ubuntu system I have to clean out the trash ( `.Trash-1000` or some other UID) directory

Comment: Suppose you put much theme's into system. Lets check `du -sh /usr/* | sort -rh`

Comment: @Costas Updated with the info above!

Comment: You can do it by yourself - the biggest on top of the output - you should see what inside of it `du -sh /usr/share/* | sort -rh` and so on.

Comment: 10GB isn't that much for a system partition for a general-purpose computer (as opposed to a specialized appliance or server).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run `du -x / >/tmp/du` to generate a breakdown of disk usage per directory on the `/` filesystem (`-x` means “don't traverse other filesystems”).

Your biggest consumers are:

- `588M    /home` — 0.6GB of user data
- `1015M   /opt` — 1GB of software that you installed manually
- `6.4G    /usr` — 6.4GB of software installed via packages
- `350M    /var` — 0.3GB of data used by system software

None of that is surprising. 9GB is plenty for a typical single-function server but it isn't very large for a desktop computer where users want to install all kinds of programs. You can use the following command to list installed packages sorted by size:

```
dpkg-query -W -f='${Installed-Size;8}  ${Package}\n' | sort -n
```

see [How do I list installed software with the installed size?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62290/how-do-i-list-installed-software-with-the-installed-size) for alternatives, including GUI ones. In particular, Synaptic lets you sort packages by size and is more convenient for removing packages on the fly. Of course, don't remove a package if you don't know what it does.